# Guice And Mockto for Junits

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, guice

I'm trying to write Junit tests for a parser. This parser creates a graph of vertices and edges from a chosen file. In the parser I'm calling the constructor of "VertexImpl" many times to create the vertices I need.

When I'm testing the parser I don't want to create actual "VertexImpl" object cause i want it to be a real **unit test**.

How do I make a mock object every time the constructor is called using "Mockito" and "Guice"?

Comment: Junit + Guice + Mockito = https://github.com/ArcBees/Jukito

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that in your test class:

```
@Inject
private YourClassToMock _myMock;

@Before
public void setUp( ) throws Exception {
    Guice.createInjector( /* Your application modules */, mockModule( ) )
         .injectMembers( this );
}

private Module mockModule( ) {
    return new AbstractModule( ) {
        @Override
        protected void configure( ) {
            bind( YourClassToMock.class ).toInstance( mock( YourClassToMock.class ) );
        }
    };
}
```

The field _myMock, instance of `YourClassToMock`, will be injected as a mock for this test, and others fields will be injected normally like in production (due to use of your application modules).

Take care, you can't define an injection twice

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want that your parser creates certain objects; well; then rewrite it to not create such objects.

What I mean is: your parser should have some "factory" object that the parser can use to create such VertexImpls. For your unit test, you "mock" that factory; thereby having full control on what the parser is supposed to do.

Please note: the code under test is the same for unit test and production usage. The only difference: in the unit test setup, the factory object is different (you want to read about dependency injection on how to do that).

Comment: So, I'm supposed to change my parser temporarily just for the unit test?

Comment: Any tutorials on how to do it with Mockito And Guice?